# Bootstrap nested views

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I want to realize the following layout with Bootstrap  elements, any suggestions?

```html
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td rowspan="2">unified columns</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Tried to do it from examples on [Bootstrap Site](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/scaffolding.html) but could not achieve the same view.

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's all rows and spans. You have one row which has inner rows and inner spans and so on.

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span2">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="span2">hello</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="span2">bootstrap</div>
                    </div>    
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="span4">
                example
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, needed to arrange the span 's but got the idea. Nice job :)